# flash action-scripting activating a laptop camera

Tags: flash

I there a way how to take photos on laptop built-in camera controlling its control using flash? Our designer is making an application to take photos using flash action script or anything PL if not possible in flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Camera. Check out the corresponding class in the [livedocs](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html).

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class CameraExample extends Sprite {
        private var video:Video;

        public function CameraExample() {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();

            if (camera != null) {
                camera.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, activityHandler);
                video = new Video(camera.width * 2, camera.height * 2);
                video.attachCamera(camera);
                addChild(video);
        } else {
            trace("You need a camera.");
        }
    }

    private function activityHandler(event:ActivityEvent):void {
        trace("activityHandler: " + event);
    }
}
```

}